# open intercom from tabbar button click

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, intercom

I have four tabs in my `tabBarController`, I want to add a fifth tab(chat tab) to open my intercom chat,

But what I want to achieve is when the user clicks the chat `tabBar` button then intercom should present on the currently opened tab and when it dismisses then it shows the same tab that it was opened on

I know it's possible but nothing coming in my head at the moment

Answer (score 0):

That's not how tab bars are used, but if want to do it anyway, you can create a custom `UITabBarController` subclass and add a button programmatically as a subview to the tab bar.